# Flutter: how to Increase count of single item in ListView builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have a here my cart screen. I have a list view in which I have 3 buttons. To increase the item count and decrease it. And a delete button.
My delete button works perfectly as it should. The problem is with the increment and decrement button. When I click on the increment button all items in the list view increments and same with the decrement. But the price updates only of the item that has been clicked. Please help me fix the issue. below is the code for my cart screen.

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: cart.getData(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Cart>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                    return const Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Your Cart is Empty',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ));
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey.shade200,
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Image(
                                    height: 80,
                                    width: 80,
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        snapshot.data![index].image.toString()),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 130,
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 5.0,
                                        ),
                                        RichText(
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          text: TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Name: ',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color:
                                                      Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                                  fontSize: 16.0),
                                              children: [
                                                TextSpan(
                                                    text:
                                                        '${snapshot.data![index].productName.toString()}\n',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold)),
                                              ]),
                                        ),
                                        RichText(
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          text: TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Unit: ',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color:
                                                      Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                                  fontSize: 16.0),
                                              children: [
                                                TextSpan(
                                                    text:
                                                        '${snapshot.data![index].unitTag.toString()}\n',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold)),
                                              ]),
                                        ),
                                        RichText(
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          text: TextSpan(
                                              text: 'Price: ' r"$",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color:
                                                      Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                                                  fontSize: 16.0),
                                              children: [
                                                TextSpan(
                                                    text:
                                                        '${snapshot.data![index].productPrice.toString()}\n',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold)),
                                              ]),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  PlusMinusButtons(
                                    addQuantity: () {
                                      dbHelper!
                                          .updateQuantity(Cart(
                                              id: index,
                                              productId: snapshot
                                                  .data![index].productId,
                                              productName: snapshot
                                                  .data![index].productName,
                                              initialPrice: snapshot
                                                  .data![index].initialPrice,
                                              productPrice: snapshot
                                                  .data![index].productPrice,
                                              quantity: snapshot
                                                  .data![index].quantity,
                                              unitTag:
                                                  snapshot.data![index].unitTag,
                                              image:
                                                  snapshot.data![index].image))
                                          .then((value) {
                                        cart.addQuantity(snapshot.data![index].quantity!);
                                        cart.addTotalPrice(double.parse(snapshot
                                            .data![index].productPrice
                                            .toString()));
                                      });
                                    },
                                    deleteQuantity: () {
                                      cart.deleteQuantity(
                                          snapshot.data![index].quantity!);
                                      cart.removeTotalPrice(double.parse(
                                          snapshot.data![index].productPrice
                                              .toString()));
                                    },
                                    text: cart.quantity.toString(),
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        dbHelper!.deleteCartItem(
                                            snapshot.data![index].id!);
                                        cart.removeCounter();
                                        cart.removeTotalPrice(double.parse(
                                            snapshot.data![index].productPrice
                                                .toString()));
                                      },
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.delete,
                                        color: Colors.red.shade800,
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  }
                }
                return const Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'Your Cart is Empty',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
                ));
              },
            ),
          ),
          Consumer<CartProvider>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  ReusableWidget(
                      title: 'Sub-Total',
                      value: r'$' + value.getTotalPrice().toStringAsFixed(2)),
                ],
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

my Cart Provider:

```
class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();
  int _counter = 0;
  int _quantity = 1;
  int get counter => _counter;
  int get quantity => _quantity;

  double _totalPrice = 0.0;
  double get totalPrice => _totalPrice;

  late Future<List<Cart>> _cart;
  Future<List<Cart>> get cart => _cart;

  Future<List<Cart>> getData() async {
    _cart = dbHelper.getCartList();
    return _cart;
  }

  void _setPrefsItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('cart_items', _counter);
    prefs.setInt('item_quantity', _quantity);
    prefs.setDouble('total_price', _totalPrice);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _getPrefsItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _counter = prefs.getInt('cart_items') ?? 0;
    _quantity = prefs.getInt('item_quantity') ?? 1;
    _totalPrice = prefs.getDouble('total_price') ?? 0;
  }

  void addCounter() {
    _counter++;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCounter() {
    _counter--;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getCounter() {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _counter;
  }

  void addQuantity(int quantity) {
    _quantity = _quantity + quantity;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteQuantity(int quantity) {
    _quantity = _quantity - quantity;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getQuantity(int quantity) {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _quantity;
  }

  void addTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice + productPrice;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice - productPrice;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  double getTotalPrice() {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _totalPrice;
  }
}
```

My Database Handler:

```
class DBHelper {
  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }
    _database = await initDatabase();
    return null;
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, 'cart.db');
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE cart(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, productId VARCHAR UNIQUE, productName TEXT, initialPrice INTEGER, productPrice INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, unitTag TEXT, image TEXT)');
  }

  Future<Cart> insert(Cart cart) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    await dbClient!.insert('cart', cart.toMap());
    return cart;
  }

  Future<List<Cart>> getCartList() async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult =
        await dbClient!.query('cart');
    return queryResult.map((result) => Cart.fromMap(result)).toList();
  }

  Future<int> deleteCartItem(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    return await dbClient!.delete('cart', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> updateQuantity(Cart cart) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    return await dbClient!.update('cart', cart.quantityMap(),
        where: "quantity = ?", whereArgs: [cart.quantity]);
  }

  Future<List<Cart>> getCartId(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await database;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryIdResult =
        await dbClient!.query('cart', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return queryIdResult.map((e) => Cart.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

My Cart Model:

```
class Cart {
  late final int? id;
  final String? productId;
  final String? productName;
  final int? initialPrice;
  final int? productPrice;
  final int? quantity;
  final String? unitTag;
  final String? image;

  Cart(
      {required this.id,
      required this.productId,
      required this.productName,
      required this.initialPrice,
      required this.productPrice,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.unitTag,
      required this.image});

  Cart.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)
      : id = data['id'],
        productId = data['productId'],
        productName = data['productName'],
        initialPrice = data['initialPrice'],
        productPrice = data['productPrice'],
        quantity = data['quantity'],
        unitTag = data['unitTag'],
        image = data['image'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'productId': productId,
      'productName': productName,
      'initialPrice': initialPrice,
      'productPrice': productPrice,
      'quantity': quantity,
      'unitTag': unitTag,
      'image': image,
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> quantityMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'quantity': quantity,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: show the cart code

Comment: @Mahi Updated my question with rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are storing same value for all products.

```
prefs.setInt('item_quantity', _quantity);
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. What is worrying me that price is getting updated correctly, It is not adding price of all the items added to the cart screen, only of the item that is being clicked. Only issue is with item count, which incremented or decremented together for all items.